# How to use the Azure Service Bus in C++

Tags: azure, qt, azureservicebus, amqp

I need to use the Azure Service Bus with C++ or Qt with C++, but I haven't found an SDK for C++.

I tried with apache Qpid PROTON using de AMQP protocol, but also without success.

My friend created an Issues: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PROTON-2276

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have not found an SDK for C++ other than the .NET one but I do not think you are referring to C++ on the .NET platform. But you can use Service Bus via REST as well, may be this will be enough for you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/.

Comment: Yes, I am not using it with .NET. I'm a little afraid to use it with REST, I would like with a lighter protocol like AMQP.